# Appropriate start of Email except Dear/Hi

Tags: email

Mostly emails start with `Dear` or `Hi`, I m writing an email to `senior`  and I think I should not use Hi, but even dont want to use Dear as well, it makes me uncomfortable, Is there any other alternative to start an email except **Dear/Hi**.

**P.S**

We dont use words like sir or madam in our office , we are required to take their names.

Comment: Related question, [Appropriate to start business email or letter with just “Dear,”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/55663/appropriate-to-start-business-email-or-letter-with-just-dear).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What style should I use in e-mail salutations to superiors, colleagues, or juniors?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/35923/what-style-should-i-use-in-e-mail-salutations-to-superiors-colleagues-or-junio)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are greetings and salutations redundant in an e-mail?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18396/are-greetings-and-salutations-redundant-in-an-e-mail)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a business environment, when writing to a colleague or partner, the practice in an "egalitarian tradition" has allowed it appropriate not to have any greeting but addressing the person directly.

The form of respect appropriate for this "egalitarian tradition" allows for prefixes such as Mr, Ms, Dr.

For example, writing to your senior director,

> Kelly,
>   I wish to inquire about the status of the new production line, which will be assembling our new design of the product.

> Dr Hardeep,
>   Tomorrow is the deadline for submission of projects for the next quarter. My dept is aware of your plans to implement the XYZ initiative this coming quarter. However, I am unable to locate the plans that your team may have submitted.

We may have situational or contextual declarations when addressing colleagues, especially to a group of colleagues.

> Congratulations John, and your team,
>   for achieving the 2015 goal of ...

> Happy new year esteemed colleagues,
>   HR is elated to announce our reaching a new agreement with the 999th union.

To a colleague who does not outrank you significantly, or who is lesser in rank,

> How are you Susan?
>   I hope you are all refreshed from your brief assignment at our Chicago office. Is it really windy up there? I am wondering when we might get a glance at the design finalized during your 2 week stint there.

> Good morning Dr Goodnite,
>   As you requested yesterday, these are the reports you requested me to request from the team supervisors.

To your supervisor, or team leader

> Hey Anna,
>   May I drop by your office before lunch to pick up my bonus check?

To your chummy colleague,

> Hey Khamisah,
>   It's 12 o'clock - lunchtime! We had plans to the mall, remember?!!

Answer (score 1):

When I write emails of that caliber, I usually would say something along the lines of:

`Greetings [name goes here],`

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Mr. James Jones
Schwartz and Company

January 1, 20176

Hello Mr. Jones:

Text . . .